# Rails 6, Webpack, Bootstrap 5 - Bootstrap doesn't compile on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I compile Bootstrap 5 on production with webpack

In javascript folder:

```
     javascript/packs/application.scss

     @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But on production webpack doesn't precompile it with **rake assets:precompile**

Every things like active_admin:

```
      @import "~@activeadmin/activeadmin/src/scss/mixins";
      @import "~@activeadmin/activeadmin/src/scss/base";
```

works ok.

production.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

enviroment.js

```
 const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
 const jquery = require('./plugins/jquery')

 const webpack = require('webpack')
 environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
 $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
 jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
 Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
 })
)


environment.plugins.prepend('jquery', jquery)
module.exports = environment
```

What is strange, when I change env in bin/webpack to development, webpack stop compile active_admin but start bootstrap :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this guide and it works well on production and development
https://dev.to/shahershamroukh/add-bootstrap-and-fontawesome-to-your-ruby-on-rails-6-application-3fm7